# Use same db connection across multiple activities wrapped in a TransactionScope in Windows Workflow Foundation?

Tags: c#, transactions, workflow-foundation, connection-pooling, transactionscope

In Windows Workflow Foundation I want to wrap multiple code activities inside a TransactionScope activity. The code activities has SQL code that inserts data into the database. I want to open a connection to the database and then use this connection in all the code activities which inserts data into the database (so that they use the same connection).

How do I do this?

Comment: By default ADO.NET handles connection pooling and will most likely share the same connection for multiple requests in the same scope. I guess the real question is why do you want to do this?

Comment: Right now I'm creating a new connection in each activity and closing it when the activity ends. I guess it's more efficient to keep the connection open if I am to use it short after

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to worry about the costs of creating new connections. ADO.NET transparently handles connection pools for you when [connecting to SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8xx3tyca.aspx). I believe the official Oracle and mySQL drivers do the same for you as well.

As long as the connection strings match, you're in good shape.